# Screen remains black unless powered on after BIOS

Tags: graphics-card, display, bios

I'm experiencing a very funny issue for some months now. Some time (days/weeks/months?) after installing a new graphics card, my screen did not find any signal via DVI until after 2–10 restarts. Without restarting, it would just toggle between *Analog* … *Digital* … *Analog* … *Digital* … while the BIOS, GRUB, and finally Windows or Linux started, and did not stop toggling without ever showing the computer image.

After some weeks, I have found out that I could quite reproducibly avoid the restart if I follow the following steps:

1. Start PC with monitor powered off
2. Wait for the BIOS to complete and GRUB to load (this is after about 10 seconds, when GRUB accesses the hard disk, which I can still hear because it is a mechanical one and not an SSD yet)
3. Wait another 2 seconds
4. Turn on the screen and wait another 2 seconds, then choose OS to start in GRUB

This feels very esoteric, and I have not found anyone having the same problem on the internet. But there must be a reason, and possibly a solution, to it – right?!

Hardware configuration looks as follows:

- Zotac GTX 960 (GM206, 2 GB)
- i5 3470, 3.2 GHz
- Gigabyte GA-Z77-D3H
- Samsung SyncMaster 205BW

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the latest bios installed?

Comment: Have you tried attaching the monitor to a different machine?

Comment: @Moab Nope. I did not change the monitor in the meantime, btw. Will upgrade when I find out how.

Comment: @jatuttle0 Don't have another one with DVI support here.